# Scenario outlines in Xamarin Test Cloud

Tags: xamarin, calabash, scenarios, xamarin-test-cloud, query-by-example

I try to run my calabash tests on Xamarin Test cloud - I realized that there are problems with running Scenario outlines which contains Example table.

```
Scenario Outline: Examine Landing Page
    #Given I open application
    Then I see the button <button>

    Examples: Buttons on Landing Page
        |button             |
        |booking history    |
        |User Preferences   |
        |Log In             |
```

Is there somebody who had similar problem and resolved them?
Is the the scenario outline working for the Xamarin Test Cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Xamarin Test Cloud does support Scenario Outlines - it looks pretty sweet. We can help look at your test suite, if you contact support.

Comment: that's not an answer, just saying

Answer (score 0):

The sample which I use there is the simplest I found in my code. Hope that small help for those will help me for others scenarios.

I found the same problem there https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/216684-xamarin-test-cloud/suggestions/5480845-add-full-support-for-gherkin-scenario-outlines - without any response.

To contact with support site want's me to install Xamarin studio - but why I do not need them?

Comment: There is no need to install Xamarin Studio. Scenario Outlines is a Cucumber feature. Please contact Test Cloud support to setup your account.